# How many 8-bit strings don't have 6 consecutive 0s?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

This is a problem from my Rosen's discrete math textbook in the Inclusion-Exclusion principle section. I'm asked to count how many 8-bit strings there are which don't contain 6 consecutive 0s. I'm not sure what I did wrong, but here's my approach:

Let $A$ be the set of bit strings of the form 000000**

Let $B$ be the set of bit strings of the form *000000*

Let $C$ be the set of bit strings of the form **000000

(Note: intentionally did not format the 0s and stars above so they line up nicely).

Okay, so here's what I know:

- By permutation, $|A| = |B| = |C| = 4$
- Looking at the overlaps, I've concluded that:

  $|A \cap B| = 5$

  $|A \cap C| = 4$

  $|B \cap C| = 5$

  $|A \cap B \cap C| = 4$

By the formula, the set of bit strings that contain 6 consecutive 0s is of size:

$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C| = 4 + 4 + 4 - 5 - 4 - 5 + 4 = 12 - 10 = 2$

Calculating the total number of possible 8-bit strings with no restrictions, I get $2^8$. Subtracting the above value from this gives $2^8 - 2$ 8-bit strings without 6 consecutive 0s.

**What did I do wrong?**

Comment: For a start you should have $|A \cap B| \le |A|$ in general

Comment: If |A| =|B|= 4, how can |A \cap B| = 5? The intersection of two sets can't have more elements than either of the sets.

Comment: List the elements you see in $A \cap B$.

Comment: $A\cap B \subset A$. Then how is $|A\cap B |>|A|$?

Comment: How can $|A \cap B| > |A|$???

Comment: another obvious issue is that in fact $|A \cap B \cap C| = 1$, the string "00000000"

Comment: How did you conclude the overlaps.  Those are very strange and incorrect results and I don't understand why you got those in the first place.

Comment: Okay, guys, chill, I made a mistake. Wouldn't be here if I didn't. So I'm guessing my issue was that I counted only the 0s for the overlaps, ignoring potential * overlaps, correct?

Comment: Edit: okay, so I re-read @Henry 's comment, and I'm now wondering why that is the only possible intersection for all 3.

Comment: If it is in A then it is in the form 000000-- so the first six are zeros.  If its in B then it is of the form -000000- so the middle 6 are zeros.  If it is in C then it is of the form --000000 so the last six are zero.  How many 8-bit strings are there where the first six, the middle six, and the last six are all zeros.  (Which terms are allowed to  *not* be zero)

Comment: Note $A\cap C = \{00000000\}$ is also has only one element.

Comment: @fleablood Brilliant, thank you for the long explanation above, that made perfect sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|A\cap B|$ are those of both $000000**$ and of the form $*000000*$ which mean the first and seventh terms are $0$ so they are of the form $0000000*$ and there are $2$ of them.

So $|A \cap B| = 2\ne 5$

$A\cap C$ are all those of the form $000000**$ and also of the form $**000000$ which means all terms are of the form $00000000$ and there is only one such.

So $|A\cap C| = 1\ne 4$

And likewise $B\cap C$ or those of the form $**000000$ and $*000000*$ so of the for $*0000000$ and there are two of them

So $|B\cap C| = 2\ne 5$.

An $|A\cap B \cap C| $ mean that are of the form $**000000, *000000*,000000**$ so all terms are $0$.  So there are $1$ of them.

So $|A\cap B\cap C| = 1$.

So there are with 6 or more consective $0$: $4 + 4+ 4 - 2-1-2+1 = 8$ such strings.  So there are $2^8 - 8$ that don't.

The eight are

$00000000$ that one is in all $A$,$B$ and $C$.

$00000011,0000010$ those two are in $A$ only.

$00000001$ that one is in $A$ and $B$.

$1000001$ that one is in $B$ only.

$1000000$ that one is in $B$ and $C$

and $11000000, 01000000$ are in $C$ only.

Comment: Thank you very much, I now see the logic behind determining the intersections.